# CMOS Buffers minimum voltage for logical high

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm looking at the datasheet for a non inverting CMOS buffer CD74HC4050 What is the lowest voltage that can be placed on 1A to cause 1Y to be logic High? I know it's somewhere in the datasheet but I new to this and don't know which value. Thanks

Datasheet https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4050.pdf?ts=1609459927711&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FCD74HC4050

Comment: So far, people are answering assuming you mean: What is the lowest voltage that can be placed on 1A to *guarantee* 1Y to be logic High? When the input is between about 30% and 70% the output is technically undefined, although the threshold is typically 50% for CMOS. So, the anal answer is 30%, but I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the minimum value of Vih:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

3.15 V is the Vih value when the chip is powered bu 4.5 V.  For both the 4.5 V and 6.0 V cases, the input threshold level is 70% of Vcc.  So ... I say that at 5.0 V the minimum input threshold voltage is 3.5 V, not 3.15 V.

Answer (score -1):

CMOS is designed so that Nch and Pch thresholds are matched so the threshold is Vdd/2.

Due to Mfg tolerances and thermal sensitivity, this data sheet defines the guaranteed thresholds as about +/-25% of Vdd/2.

Comment: This answer with tolerances is correct. Vih and Vil are a ratio metric wrt.Vdd Ignore the troll-1